# Why does my anti-duplicate file loop not function?

Tags: java

I am creating a project where a random "UserID" is generated when the user wants to add a customer. Along with this UserID, a file is created with the formatted userID which contains user entered first name and last name. I am currently using random to generate user ID's, and created a do while loop to avoid possible duplicate. In the final project, I will have random set to pull from 9999, but for demonstration and duplicate testing purposes, it is set to 1.

All of the sudden, my do-while loop is not functioning as it has been. I have tried moving a few things around, checking syntax and changing directories, but nothing is working.

Why is my do-while loop that serves as an anti-duplicate file method not working?

```
  public static void userAddition() throws IOException
  {
     boolean retry = true;
     String formattedUserId = "";
     Random randomNumbers = new Random();
     int userId;
     final int MAX_RETRIES = 10;


     int retryCount = 0;
     do
     {
        retryCount++;
        userId = randomNumbers.nextInt(1);
        formattedUserId = String.format("%04d", userId);
        File f = new File("C:/Users/Nick/Desktop/Library" + formattedUserId + ".txt");
        retry = f.exists();
      }
      while (retry && retryCount < MAX_RETRIES);




      if (retry)
      {
        System.out.println("Error");
      }
      else
      {
        // happy path
        String userFirstName = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the customer's first name:");
        String userLastName = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the customer's last name:");



        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(formattedUserId + ".txt", true);
        PrintWriter outputFile = new PrintWriter(fw);

        outputFile.printf("#%s%n", formattedUserId);
        outputFile.printf("%s %s", userFirstName, userLastName);

        System.out.println(formattedUserId);
        outputFile.close(); 
      }

   }
```

}

I expect the do-while loop to run through 10 times, before hitting the MAX_RETRIES and displaying "Error".

Comment: nextInt(1) will always return 0.

Comment: what exactly do you mean 'not working' -what does it do?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please try to remove all the unnecessary stuff. You want *us* to help you with *your* code, but you bother us with a lot of code which does not contribute to finding the error. By doing your part of work and extracting the Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example (https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), you might often even find your error yourself. What for example does the whole happy path to do with your error? Cannot you reduce the code even more so you really leave here just the malfunctioning "core"?

Comment: @murksiuke The do-while loop specifically is supposed to generate the random number, format it, and then check if that file already exists, and if it does exist, reloop the do. With the current setup I expect it to continuously loop until it reaches the max error, but instead it just writes over the already existing file.

Comment: @alpert Yes, for the testing purpose I wanted it to generate the same number. The do-while loop is supposed to make sure that the file name "0000.txt" doesnt already exist before continuing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You test for the existence of file `C:/Users/Nick/Desktop/Library0000.txt`:

```
File f = new File("C:/Users/Nick/Desktop/Library" + formattedUserId + ".txt");
```

Then you create the file in the folder of the project with the name `0000.txt`:

```
FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(formattedUserId + ".txt", true);
```

So your test for existence will *never* return true :)

The easy fix is to store the calculated file name in a variable:

```
String fileName = String.format("C:/Users/Nick/Desktop/Library/%04d.txt", userId);
File f = new File(fileName);
...

FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(fileName, true);
```

By the way, have a look at [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html), you **should** use it like this:

```
try (Writer writer = new PrintWriter(FileWriter(fileName, true))) {
    writer.printf("#%s%n", formattedUserId);
    writer.printf("%s %s", userFirstName, userLastName);
    // notice: no close(), this is handled automatically and better!
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I was missing "/" after library. I feel very stupid.